# как тестировать методы, в которых есть вероятность java

Tags: java, тестирование, junit

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в JUnit (если такое возможно), тестировать методы, у которых есть вероятность некоторого события. У меня есть метод, который принимает String и возвращает String, но при его вызове у меня генерируется рандомное число до 100. И в зависимости от того, какое число сгенерировалось, есть 3 варианта того, какой String вернет метод. Соответственно, я не могу написать:

```
@TEST
public void myMethodTest() {
String s = "какое-то сообщение";
assertEquals("ожидаемое сообщение", myMethod(s));
}
```

потому, что я не знаю, что именно вернет мне метод. Я так предполагаю, что я как-то должен детерменировать это самое сгенерированное число, но оно генерируется внутри метода, я не могу его ему передать. Как тестируются такие методы?

Comment: выделите генерилку числа в отдельный класс и замокайте и все, не будет у вас вероятности.

Comment: Можно сделать набор (например, HashSet), проверять, что результат принадлежит набору. Можно сделать кучу тестов, и проверит, что, скажем, на 100 тестах выпадает все 3 значения (при условии, что тесты выполняются быстро и вероятность событий примерно одинакова -- то есть вероятность ложного фейла теста должна быть очень и очень мала, а сами тесты -- относительно быстры). Делать заглушку не всегда правильно, т.к. может получится "тест ради теста": разумеется, тест должен тестировать не сам тест, а близкую к реальности функциональность

Comment: @MikhailIonkin заглушку делают, чтобы результат теста был детерминирован. Если ваши тесты зависят от ветоятности, то они 1) очень хрупкие 2) Зачем то тестируют геренилку рандомов

Comment: Я и пытаюсь проверить функциональность. У меня в одном из случаев не просто String возвращается, а делается определенная логика с принятым на вход String'ом и там тоже возможны варианты, что именно придет, но оно как раз детерминировано (if-else). Вопрос в том, как мне попасть в эту вероятность, которая вызовет ту самую проверяемую логику. Я думаю про какой-нибудь Mockito, но еще не изучал его. Может он помочь в этом?

Comment: см первый комментарий под вопросом.

Comment: То есть я правильно понимаю, что мне нужно переписать метод так, чтобы он на вход принимал еще и мое рандомное число от отдельного класса, потом делать тот самый mock и уже тогда тестировать?

Comment: Вы можете написать свой класс с методом getNextRandomNumber()  или попрбовать замокать тот, который используете сейчас. Как этот класс передавть в ваш код зависит о библиотеки, что вы используете  - я предпочитаю передавать такие классы через конструктор.

Comment: все верно вам подсказывают про моки и mockito вам в помощь (в нагрузку к junit)

Comment: Спасибо за ответы!